# Why doesn't std::sets of alglib::real_1d_array work in this case?

Tags: c++, set, alglib

I'm forking a C++ program using Alglib so that I can invert matrices and do matrix multiplications easily.

Right now I'm facing this error:

Invalid operands to binary expression ('const alglib::real_1d_array' and 'const alglib::real_1d_array')

So what caused this error?

```
 inline vecset getAdmittedCVectors(void)
 {
        return admittedCVectors;
 }
```

Here vecset means

```
typedef std::set<alglib::real_1d_array> vecset;
```

and admittedCVectors is a member of a class.

```
vecset admittedCVectors;
```

How shall I solve it? Using a variant of std::set that does not have this issue or overloading < in alglib::real_1d_array which is much harder?

Comment: `std::set` requires that its elements be less-than comparable. Does `alglib::real_1d_array` support such comparison?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh! Definitely not unless I try to define this operation. OK it seems that I need to look for alternative collections. Well I don't think even == is actually overloaded for alglib::real_1d_array..so maybe I should give up on the idea of using set-like structures for it.

Comment: If the type doesn't have overloads for the `<` or `==` operators, it doesn't sound like you need the collection to be ordered or unique. Have you considered `std::vector`?

Comment: @JohnIlacqua Well I do want the collection to be unique but do not want it to be ordered. == can be implemented. However I'm probably not going to be able to modify alglib very soon so maybe I will use a different collection.

Comment: then perhaps `unordered_set`? (though this requires a hash function and ==)